# finding the slop and y intercept of a line

Tags: python-3.x, line

I am trying to make a function where it find the slope and y int of a Line from two points, and return it to a list.

```
def find(p1, p2):
```

However I'm having trouble finding out how the user would input in a coordinate for `p1` as (2,10) and `p2` (4,16) when there are only two input parameters?

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are probably expected to be a tuples, not single numbers. Then you'd call the function like `find((12, 34), (56, 78))`.

Comment: yes I was thinking that to

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `input()` returns a string, so you can ask the user to enter a number in a certain format, then parse it into a tuple of the two coordinates:

```
p = input('Enter a point as #,#: ')
p = tuple(int(x) for x in p.split(','))
print('p =',p)
```

Result:

```
Enter a point as #,#: 10,12
p = (10, 12)
```

You can break the two components apart with the following to do a calculation:

```
x,y = p
```

Or just use `p[0]` and `p[1]` to access the first and second coordinates.

Tie it all together with:

```
def get_point():
    p = input('Enter a point as #,#: ')
    p = tuple(int(x) for x in p.split(','))
    return p

def find(p1,p2):
    x1,y1 = p1
    x2,y2 = p2
    # do calculation
    # return result

p1 = get_point()
p2 = get_point()
result = find(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Could you make this into just one function?

Comment: also could you explain what the `p = tuple(int(x) for x in p.split(','))` does

Comment: @nick Why?  Functions are so you don't have to repeat yourself.  This sounds like homework, so I'll leave that as an exercise for you :^)  `.split()` breaks a string into a list of strings, in this case, splitting on a comma.  `int(x)` converts a string into an integer.  The rest iterates over the list of strings converting them to integers, then puts the integers in a tuple.  The code inside `tuple` is called a *generator expression* if you want to look up how it works.